# How do I create shortcut to the Start screen on the Desktop?

Tags: windows-8-preview

If you let normal people use Windows 8, they are lost as soon as they get to the Desktop. They stop there, not figuring out on their own how to get to the Start screen, to launch apps.

That's why I think it is very important to be able to create a "Show Start" shortcut on the Desktop.

I have made some research and I cannot figure it out. It seems that the Start screen doesn't have its own separate executable, to which you can easily create a shortcut. It seems to be Windows Explorer running in some special mode, with special parameters. However, I cannot figure out which are those.

Does anybody have any good ideas for how to create such a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I made lots of research + testing and found a way. Not ideal but there is one:

- write a script that sends the keystrokes required to launch the Start screen;
- convert that script to an exe file;
- change the icon of the file to look like a *Show Start Screen* shortcut.

For anyone that's interested, the end result can be found here: [Download the Shortcut to the Windows 8 Start Screen for the Desktop](http://www.7tutorials.com/download-shortcut-windows-8-start-screen-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your desktop background to a picture on which you've superimposed some text - `Press Windows Key For Start Menu` perhaps. Or put a file/shortcut on the desktop whose name says that.